# Xamarin toast message only working in emulator

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-toast

I am trying to display a toast message in a Xamarin application targeting Android with the following C# code:

```
[Activity(Label = "Storyvoque", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity, ICommandExecutionContext, IStoryHostContext, IProgress<string>
...
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    ...
        try
        {
           RunOnUiThread(() =>
           {
              try
              {
                 using (var toast = Toast.MakeText(this, Resource.String.msg_story_saved, ToastLength.Short))
                    toast.Show();
                 ShowMessage("OK");
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                 ShowMessage(ex.Message);
              }
           });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           ShowMessage(ex.Message);
        }
   ...
   private void ShowMessage(string message)
   {
      RunOnUiThread(() =>
      {
         AlertDialog dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
         dlgAlert.SetMessage(message);
         dlgAlert.SetButton("Close", (s, args) =>
         {
            dlgAlert.Dismiss();
            dlgAlert.Dispose();
         });
         dlgAlert.Show();
      });
   }
```

Everything works fine in my AVD_for_Nexus_6_by_Google emulated device running Android 6.0 API Level 23. I get a toast message and a message box that says "OK". But when I run the same application on my Nexus 6P running Android 8.1.0, the "OK" message appears, but no toast messsage appears. Even without the OK message the toast message wasn't appearing. I checked the app's notification settings; I don't have notifications disabled for any of my apps. How can I find the source of this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the resources are being built correctly? Especially when changing devices, it can help to clean the solution and rebuild.

Comment: Have you tried with 'Application.Context'?

Comment: why are you calling the toast.Show() in a ui thread? Call it outside and let me know if it works

Comment: @G.hakim I tried removing `RunOnUiThread`, rebuilding and re-deploying the app to my device. Now it works. But then I tried the other code that was still using `RunOnUiThread` and also failing yesterday, and now it works too. So something else changed that caused Toast messages to start working on my device, and I don't know what it was.